# last one or two lines are hidden or covered on the given pdf file

Tags: pdftex

In some pages, last one or two lines are hidden on the given pdf file. What if I ask you about how to recover/restore those lines in the pdf file?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! We haven't any idea how you produce your document. In normal circumstances this should not happed, this lines should be moved to the next page. Maybe adding `\raggedbottom` command to your document preamble will help you.